# Opencv Assertion failed with darknet

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, darknet

I used to have OPENCV 3.4.1 installed on Ubuntu 18.04. I tried to compile YOLO3 on my machine and it failed to compile which lead me to [this issue](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/485). One of the suggestions in that issue suggested to use 3.4.0 and it kinda worked.

I used these options with cmake:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-3.4.0/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

then I did

```
make -j8    
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

With opencv 3.4.0 I was able to compile it. However when i try to run it I was getting the error(shown below). It is weird because i just installed 3.4.0 and  it is showing some error related to 3.4.1.

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed ((flags & FIXED_TYPE) != 0) in type, file <local_path>/opencv-3.4.1/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp, line 807
```

It is not supposed to show that 3.4.1 error when i don't even have it installed. I also removed the directory in which i compiled 3.4.1 earlier and still the error is pointing to the removed directory(`<local_path>/opencv-3.4.1/`).  is in my home folder with lot of weirdly named directories.So I excluded it to avoid any confusion.

I was able to confirm that 3.4.0 is installed with:

```
# han @ falcon in ~ [19:36:41] 
$ /usr/local/bin/opencv_version
3.4.0
```

I want to know what is causing the error mentioned above(the one related to assertion)

Comment: probably the 3.4.2 libraries are still installed in the system and the symlinks of opencv libs still point to them. try the command locate opencv*.so or sth.

Comment: That happened because sudo apt-get purge libopencv* did not yield any result when i ran it on ZSH( got an error saying "no matches found: libopencv*"). But same command on bash removed those config files and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

That happened because `sudo apt-get purge libopencv*` did not yield any result when i ran it on ZSH( got an error saying "no matches found: libopencv*" which I overlooked). But same command on bash removed the config files from earlier installation.

Darknet won't compile with opencv 3.4.1. So i suggest downgrading opencv to 3.4.0. If you want to run it on 3.4.1 look into  [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10963#issue) issue on Github.